# "something(s) of A and B is similar" vs "something of A is similar to that/those of B"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are these two sentences the same? Which one is preferred?

> 1 The overall dynamics of a new car and an old car are similar.

> 2 The overall dynamics of a new car are similar to those of an old car.

An other example:

> 3 The color of my shirt and your shirt is similar.

> 4 The color of my shirt is similar to that of your shirt.

Comment: 3 should read "*The **colours** ... **are** similar.*"

Comment: They're all correct and natural if you make my suggested grammar adjustment. The second version sounds slightly more formal and more precise.